# Is there a "grace period" between close question and delete

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

A question was closed after 12 hours and deleted after 10 hours. I searched on meta to know if there is a grace period for re-open and some post mentioned it was 2 days. So can someone confirm if it is 10 hours or 2 days.

Comment: There's no real grace period--a moderator can delete a question at any time, open or closed. However, if a question can be *salvaged*, a decent rule of thumb is to give the OP two days to fix it.

Comment: @simchona note that's on a mod-by-mod basis.  No such rule-of-thumb exists on SO for example.

Comment: @jolly Yup, which is why I tried not to imply that it's a rule for all of us

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two day "grace period" you talk about primarily affects the owner of the question: they can't delete their own closed questions immediately, and have to wait 48h to do so.

Users with a reputation between 10k and 20k cannot vote to delete questions immediately either, they can only do so for questions that have been closed for 48h, a bit like the owner of the question.
Trusted users (20k+) can vote to delete a question immediately after it has been closed, no waiting period enforced. (Three votes are required for deletion in both cases).

Moderators can close and delete questions immediately and single-handedly.