# How can I flag a closed question for deletion?

Tags: support

On what basis can I flag for moderation attention to delete a closed question?

I know [there is no grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161048/is-there-a-grace-period-between-close-question-and-delete) between closed questions and deletion so now I just want to know how to phrase my reasoning for deletion.